# Android TimePicker methods being stubs

Tags: android, android-timepicker

(I am unsure if everyone else faces this problem, but I do)
I am accessing `setHour(int)` and `getHour()` (and the minute's getter and setter) of android.widget.TimePicker - IntelliJ doesn't complain of their inexistence, but when i run the program from my phone (or emulator) it crashes and i see an error log of `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError android.widget.TimePicker.getHour`. (Other minute/hour getter/setter include).
I tried accessing the definition for the TimePicker class (Ctrl+B) and I realised every method contained a line: throw RuntimeException("Stub");
So what's this; How can I move on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> IntelliJ doesn't complain of their inexistence

That is because you are compiling against API Level 23.

> but when i run the program from my phone (or emulator) it crashes and i see an error log of java.lang.NoSuchMethodError android.widget.TimePicker.getHour

That is because [`getHour()` was added in API Level 23](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#getHour%28%29), and your device or emulator is running Android 5.2 or below.

I don't use IntelliJ, but it should be complaining about your build. In Eclipse and Android Studio, you would get an error from Lint indicating that you are calling a method (`getHour()`) that exists in your `compileSdkVersion` (23) but does not exist in your `minSdkVersion` (whatever you have that set to, as the oldest API level that you are willing to support).

> I tried accessing the definition for the TimePicker class (Ctrl+B) and I realised every method contained a line: throw RuntimeException("Stub")

That is because it is decompiling the `android.jar` that is in your compile-time classpath, which consists purely of stub implementations to satisfy the **`javac`** compiler. At runtime, your process' VM will have a version of that JAR that has actual implementations.

> How can I move on?

Probably stop calling `getHour()`, unless you can get away with doing so only on Android 6.0+ devices.

Comment: I seem to understand. How else should i `setHour()` because in the API docs online I dont get any help

Comment: @DegreatYartey: [Use `setCurrentHour()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#setCurrentHour%28java.lang.Integer%29).